# RETRIEVE DATA in combox and show realted fields data in textfields C#

Tags: c#, combobox

I am using SQL Server 2008 database. My database table name is customer and I got names of customers in combo-box. I want to show the data like address and contact number of selected customer in text fields. Please help

```
void fillbox()
{
    sqlconc.Open();
    sqlcmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM customer";
    dr = sqlcmd.ExecuteReader();
    if (dr.HasRows)
    {
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Add(dr[1].ToString());
        }
    }
    sqlconc.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really get your question. But, it seems you want to concatenate multiple fields to display in your dropdown right?

You can use this:

```
List<Customer> customers = new List<Customer>();
customers.Add(new Customer() { CustomerId = 1, CustomerName = "Foo",    CustomerAddress="A", ContactNo = "1" });
customers.Add(new Customer() { CustomerId = 2, CustomerName = "Bar", CustomerAddress="B", ContactNo = "2" });

var customerQuery = customers.Select(c => new { CustomerId = c.CustomerId, DisplayText = c.CustomerAddress.ToString() + " " + c.ContactNo });

skuDropDown.DataSource = customerQuery ;
skuDropDown.DataValueField = "CustomerId";
skuDropDown.DataTextField = "DisplayText";
skuDropDown.DataBind();
```